# Cannot do model binding with Django ModelForm

Tags: python, django, modelform

Suppose I have a model class in Python:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=300)
    description = models.CharField('Description', max_length=800)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField('Pulished Date')
    question_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

And I want to bind it with a ModelForm:

```
class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('title', 
              'description', 
              'publish_date', 
              'question_type')
```

When I try to create an object in the shell, I get this error:

```
>>> form = QuestionForm()
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> form.publish_date = timezone.now().year
>>> form.save()
IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'publish_date' cannot be null")
```

Did I miss anything here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes: you've missed the entire purpose of forms.

Just manually assigning a property with the same name as the model property will do nothing at all. That's not how forms work. Forms work by taking a `data` parameter, which is a dictionary mapping fieldnames to values. Then you call `form.is_valid()` to validate it. Only then you can you call `form.save()`.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that ModelForm automatically bind the data model. If it doesn't, what's so special to use it instead of regular form class?

Comment: Oh I get what you mean. So if I do an assignment operation, the form object won't map it directly?

Comment: Direct assignment isn't the use case of any type of form - as I said, they're for validation of posted data. And the point of a ModelForm is that it automatically creates fields that map to your model fields, c and provides a save method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [add validation to your form or to your field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/).

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=300)
    description = models.CharField('Description', max_length=800)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField('Pulished Date', blank=False)
    question_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

In the above snippet, you can make sure that `published_date` was entered by using `blank=False`. As Daniel pointed out, you also need to call `form.is_valid()` before saving the data.